# Подчеркнуть строку в документе Microsoft Word используя Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word

Tags: c#

Подскажите, как мне подчеркнуть строку где было найдено слово?

```
        var wordApp = new Word.Application();
        wordApp.Visible = true;
        wordApp.Documents.Open(@"C:\Users\Администратор\Desktop\1.docx");
        Word.Find findWords = wordApp.Selection.Find;
        findWords.Text = "Ключевое слово";
```

Answer (score 1):

```
var path = "Путь";
var wordApp = new Word.Application();
var document = wordApp.Documents.Open(path);
var range = worDocument.Content;
range.Find.ClearFormatting();

if (range.Find.Execute("Что ищешь"))
{
    range.Font.Underline = Word.WdUnderline.wdUnderlineSingle;
}
```